# How to save a masked array to png with transparent pixels?

Tags: python, numpy, png

I have a masked numpy array (e.g. 2000x2000, dtype=np.uint16).

I want to store it as a png file in gray-scale with alpha channel. The pixels should have the value of the element but be transparent for masked elements.

What would be the best way to do it?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: you mean these masked elements should be transparent? because the alpha channel will be contained for every pixel!

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll edit the question for clarity.

Comment: I think the matplotlib function `imsave` does the job for you automatically

Comment: Matplotlib saved as 8-bit pixels. However, I found numpngw that solved it in 5 min. A very friendly package. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpngw